# Can't specify class path in Java

Tags: java, classpath

I have a Test.jar file with ru.package.Tester class in it. When I run the following command in the directory with my jar:

```
java -classpath /path/to/current/directory ru.package.Tester
```

I get the following error message:

```
Could not find or load main class
```

I'm running on OS X

upd: When I put my jar file into /Library/Java/Extensions, it all works without specifying -classpath.

Comment: Do you have a manifest with `Main class`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give path to jar

```
java -classpath /path/to/current/directory/your.jar ru.package.Tester
```

Comment: How do I add more than one jar file in this case?

Comment: You can add multiple paths using `:` as a separator:  `/path/to/current/directory/first.jar:/path/to/current/directory/second.jar`. You can also use wildcards:  `/path/to/current/directory/*`

Answer (score 0):

could you please check your **~/.bash_profile** - what does it contain . I too faced the similar issue on my mac yesterday and got it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the classpath. By default, Java looks for the classes directly in the directory. If you want to run a jar, you must tell Java to do so:

```
java -jar your.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check manifest file. it must contain main class name in manifest.